# javascript: passing the key from for loop to another function fails

Tags: javascript, loops, object, arguments, key

I'm trying to pass the key from a for loop to another function and get data from an object there. For some reason when I pass the key, it tells me it's undefined.

```
//this is the for loop from where I call anotherFunction
for (var key in object) { // note that this is not an array but an object 
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {               
        console.log("test :"+ anotherObject[key]["anotherProperty"]); //this works
        anotherFunction(key);               
    }
}

function anotherFunction(arg){ 
    console.log("arg: "+arg); //shows the correct argument
    console.log("test2: "+anotherObject["myProperty"]["anotherProperty"]); //this works, in other words, if I manually type the correct property it works but I want to be able to use the passed along argument
    console.log("test3: "+anotherObject[arg]["anotherProperty"]); //this doesn't work
    var arg2 = '"'+arg+'"'; //I tried adding quote characters       
    console.log("test4: "+anotherObject[arg2]["anotherProperty"]); //this doesn't work  
}
```

The error it shows is: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anotherProperty' of undefined at etc

Any idea why it won't work and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my fiddle, all works
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4d4s/)

try `console(anotherObject);`

may your object alittle not correct